# Passing rowdata tag from javascript to servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have a jsp file where on a button click a bunch of rows shows up in a html table format.

The rows have checkboxes as well. When I click a checkbox and hit another button i am able to retrieve the selected row tags and push them into an array.

How can I pass this array to the servlet\scriptlet.

Array consists of tags like so: `'< td > hi < /td> <td>ho</td>','< td > hi < /td> <td>ho< /td>'`,....

I included json2.js and tried stringify but servlet always comes back saying null when i use request.getparametervalues()

i also dont have a submit form so that rules out the submit form part of the coding.

Any and all advices very much appreciated.

code in js:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'book.jsp',
    data: JSON.stringify({ nameParameter: colheader }),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success:function(data){alert(data);},
    error:function(){alert('error');}
});
```

Code in scriptlet book.jsp

```
String[] arrayData=request.getParameterValues("nameParameter");
System.out.println("########nameParameter"+arrayData);
```

Comment: Before sending the ajax request alert this :
`alert(colheader);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

I add a rowid to each checkbox with the value of the primary key.

On selected a checkbox I post the rowid's to the scriptlet using the below

```
$.post('target.jsp', { id: selectedrows });
```

selectedrows is an array of selected rowids.

I set the resultset obtained into the session in the jsp.

I retrieve the resultset from the session in my scriptlet (target.jsp) and filter based on my selected rowids. That way I have all the values and need not pass the entire rowtag.

Alternatively you can query the database again with the selected rowid's, I chose not to do it as my resultset does not hold more than 100 rows.